# Как сделать так, чтобы EditText в landscape режиме не разворачивался на весь экран?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Как сделать так, чтобы EditText в landscape режиме не разворачивался на весь экран?

Comment: Поставить ширину не на весь экран?..

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле по запросу "EditText no fullscreen": http://stackoverflow.com/a/4726646/2893248

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Либо добавляете в xml разметку EditText `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"`, либо в коде `editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI)`

Comment: Пробовал. Не работает

Comment: Разобрался. android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" - я пихал в AndroidManifest, именно поэтому не работало.